# Cassandra driver exception "All host(s) tried for query failed" occurs every few hours without explanation

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have an issue with my Cassandra cluster (4 node cluster). Cassandra version is 2.2.9 and driver version is 3.0.3.
After a couple of hours (~ 3 hours) I see the following issues in the driver log:

1. OutOfDirectMemoryError (Occurs sporadic and most of the time without impact)
2. No protocol version matching integer version
3. Unknown response opcode
4. Heartbeat query timed out
5. All host(s) tried for query failed --> Can't query Cassandra anymore

The Cassandra cluster is healthy and when I restart the app everything works again for a couple of hours.

Log snippet:

```
First Time                       Count  Message
2017-11-11 19:03:03 +0100            51  [/??.???.??.??:????] preparing to open ? new connections, total = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:03 +0100            49  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=false] Transport initialized, connection ready
2017-11-11 19:03:03 +0100            24  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=true] closed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             1  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate ??????? byte(s) of direct memory (used: ???????, max: ????????))
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100            14  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] failed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             7  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=??, closed=false] failed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             1  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=??, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No protocol version matching integer version ?)
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             5  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=??, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ??)
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             4  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ?)
2017-11-11 19:03:29 +0100             3  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode -???)
2017-11-11 19:03:30 +0100             3  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ??)
2017-11-11 19:03:30 +0100             2  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ??)
2017-11-11 19:03:30 +0100           401  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=false] failed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:33 +0100             1  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ???)
2017-11-11 19:03:41 +0100           722  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Heartbeat query timed out
2017-11-11 19:03:41 +0100             8  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-?, inFlight=?, closed=false] failed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:41 +0100            11  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-?, inFlight=?, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Heartbeat query timed out
2017-11-11 19:03:41 +0100            67  [/??.???.??.??:????] Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-??, inFlight=?, closed=false] failed, remaining = ???
2017-11-11 19:03:41 +0100           115  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-??, inFlight=?, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Heartbeat query timed out
2017-11-11 19:03:44 +0100             2  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=??, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unknown response opcode ?)
2017-11-11 19:03:51 +0100             2  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Heartbeat query timed out
2017-11-11 19:03:51 +0100           265  Failed to post timeseries data Error Returned - 
2017-11-11 19:03:57 +0100             3  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=??, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Heartbeat query timed out
2017-11-11 19:04:01 +0100            39  Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=?, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Operation timed out
2017-11-11 19:04:01 +0100            12  Error processing jobs: execution of statement failed:All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /??.???.??.??:???? (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)), /??.???.??.??:???? (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)), /??.???.??.??:???? (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)), /??.???.??.??:???? [only showing errors of first ? hosts, use getErrors() for more details])
```

Does somebody have an idea what could be the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the direct memory settings you are using for your application. Ensure that there is enough memory available which can be allocated by the driver. Cassandra needs to allocate the direct memory. In cases where it cannot allocate the memory I already saw similar issues where it was reported as NoHostAvailableException even if it was memory related.

Answer (score 3):

```
Defuncting Connection[/??.???.??.??:????-???, inFlight=???, closed=false] because: [/??.???.??.??:????] Unexpected exception triggered (io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate ??????? byte(s) of direct memory (used: ???????, max: ????????))
```

You have some memory issues. You can't expect the driver to work properly as long as these issues exists. You also say that your application stops working after a couple of hours. To me it sounds like you have memory leaks in your application.